# Difference between window.pageYOffset and document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top ?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a progress bar depending on how much you scroll. Which of these two should I use?

```
function getScrollValue() {
    return ((parseInt(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top) * -1));
}
```

or

```
function getScrollValue() {
    return window.pageYOffset;
}
```

Comment: [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) is probably the better solution for that.

Comment: Use window.pageYOffset (IntersectionObserver is not supported by IE)

Comment: @JakobE There is a [polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill).

Comment: Yep - but in this case (just monitoring page scroll) it's overkill (the polyfill also uses scroll listeners). I would use scroll listeners and passive events if available

Comment: @JakobE IntersectionObserver exists because the naive solution to scroll handlers often impose performance problems. It is not overkill to enhance performance for capable browsers while providing a polyfill for heavily outdated browsers.

Comment: I'm aware of that – the costs of implementing a polyfill intended to do much more than monitoring a scroll position is IMO higher than using the simpler scroll listener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185840/discussion-between-jakob-e-and-str).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides of `window.pageYOffset` being the more specialized API as well as a more performant solution for detecting the scrolling value, using `getBoundingClientRect().top` for attempting the same thing can have unexpected results if, for instance, the body has some margin-top that offsets its position.

EDIT

I've included the following [jsPerf Test](https://jsperf.com/scroll-calc-api) that shows a substantial difference of performance between the two alternatives, as well as how a third (older) API fares against them.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example using the progress bar tag

```js
/* test if passive events are supported */
var supportsPassive = false;
try { var opts = Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', { get: function() { supportsPassive = true; }});
  window.addEventListener("testPassive", null, opts);
  window.removeEventListener("testPassive", null, opts);
} catch (e) {}

/* progress element */
const progress = document.querySelector('progress');

/* scroll listener */
addEventListener('scroll', e => {
    progress.value = pageYOffset/(document.body.clientHeight - innerHeight);
}, supportsPassive ? { passive: true } : false);
```

```css
/* stretch and fix progress */ 
progress { width: 100%; position: fixed; }

/* add some scroll to the page */
body { margin: 0; height: 20000px; }
```

```html
<progress value="0"></progress>
```